# Letter and number count in raw_input

Tags: python, raw-input

I am trying to make a password strength tester. The password needs to have at least 4 numbers and 6 letters, so I need to find out how many of each were entered by the user in `raw_input`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just iterate over the password:

```
import string

numbers = 0
letters = 0

for letter in raw_input('Enter a password: '):
  if letter in string.ascii_letters:
    letters += 1
  elif letter in string.digits:
    numbers += 1

print numbers, letters
```

Answer (score 9):

```
text = "helloworld42"

numbers = sum(c.isdigit() for c in text)
letters = sum(c.isalpha() for c in text)
```